# CSS select every <a> except in <div id='exclude'>

Tags: html, css, selector

Hey I am wondering how I can implement the `css selector` for 
select every `<a>`-Tag except in a `div` tag with an id `<div id='exclude'>`.
It seems that I have to use the :`not()` selector.
CSS Selector `div#exclude a` are the links that I don't want
It is not `a:not(div#exclude a)`, isn't it?

Comment: You can't really do that. The `:not` selector is referred to the element you are selecting.

Comment: of course you can. [see here](https://jsfiddle.net/d2wqqakt/)

Comment: body > a,
body *:not(#exclude) a
{
  color: yellow;
}